# C# How to get the size of an object generated in OpenGL from Tao library

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, opengl-compat

I'm building an app that can show 3D view of STL files in a SimpleOpenGlControl using TAO.FreeGlut and TAO.OpenGL referencies. I need to get the size of the displayed 3D model for some feature but can't find it. How can I get the size of the displayed object?

I have found a basic project that can display a STL file here https://github.com/batu92k/STL-Viewer

But it has very little explanation and comments are in Turk...

I have also find some information here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23778/OpenGL-3D-Navigation2-With-Tao-and-C-Tao-OpenGL-Ta

But again, ot much explaination about size.

OpenGLMonitor Code:

```
  Batu_GL glController;
  Batu_GL.VAO_TRIANGLES modelVAO;
  BaseConfig baseConfig = new BaseConfig();

  int scale = 30;
  int rotationZ = 0;

  public OpenGLMonitor()
  {
     /* dot/comma selection for floating point numbers */
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
     Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

     InitializeComponent();

     glController = new Batu_GL();
     glController.initialize(monitor);
     glController.glInit(monitor, Batu_GL.Ortho_Mode.CENTER);
     rotationZ = baseConfig.rotationZ;
  }

  public void Draw()
  {
     glController.glDinamik(monitor, Batu_GL.Ortho_Mode.CENTER);
     //--------------------------------------------
     Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHTING);  // Activer l'éclairage
     Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHT1);
     //--------------------------------------------
     //--Lumiere 1                               
     Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT0, Gl.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, baseConfig.light_1); // Le type et le nombre de feux sont déterminés"
     Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT0, Gl.GL_SPECULAR, baseConfig.specular); // La réflexion est sélectionnée parmi les types d'éclairage. Le tableau spéculaire est utilisé pour déterminer les caractéristiques de la lumière de réflexion.
     Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT0, Gl.GL_POSITION, baseConfig.lightPos); // La position de la lumière "0" provient du tableau "lightpos"
     Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHT0); // La lumière "0" est activée
     //-------------------------------------------
     //--Lumiere 2
     Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT1, Gl.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, baseConfig.light_1);
     Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT1, Gl.GL_SPECULAR, baseConfig.specular);
     Gl.glLightfv(Gl.GL_LIGHT1, Gl.GL_POSITION, baseConfig.lightPos2);
     Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_LIGHT1);
     //-------------------------------------------
     Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL); // Activation du matériau de couleur de la pièce
     Gl.glColorMaterial(Gl.GL_FRONT, Gl.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);
     Gl.glMaterialfv(Gl.GL_FRONT, Gl.GL_SPECULAR, baseConfig.specref);
     Gl.glMateriali(Gl.GL_FRONT, Gl.GL_SHININESS, 15); // Ajuster le niveau de luminosité (bonne réflexion de "1")
     Gl.glEnable(Gl.GL_NORMALIZE); // Adoucissement de la transmission de la lumière
     //-------------------------------------------

     Gl.glRotatef(baseConfig.rotationX, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
     Gl.glRotatef(baseConfig.rotationZ, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
     rotationZ++;

     rotationZ = rotationZ % 360;

     Gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -150.0f);

     modelVAO.Draw();

     monitor.SwapBuffers();
  }

  private void fileSelectBt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     OpenFileDialog stldosyaSec = new OpenFileDialog();
     stldosyaSec.Filter = "STL Files|*.stl;*.txt;";
     scale = (int)(0.05 * monitor.Width);

     if (stldosyaSec.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
        lblFilename.Text = stldosyaSec.SafeFileName;

        STLReader stlReader = new STLReader(stldosyaSec.FileName);
        TriangleMesh[] meshArray = stlReader.ReadFile();
        modelVAO = new Batu_GL.VAO_TRIANGLES();

        STLExport stlExporter = new STLExport();

        modelVAO.parameterArray = stlExporter.Get_Mesh_Vertices(meshArray);
        modelVAO.normalArray = stlExporter.Get_Mesh_Normals(meshArray);
        modelVAO.color = Color.AntiqueWhite;
        modelVAO.scale = new float[3] { scale, scale, scale };

        if (!stlReader.Get_Process_Error())
        {
           //rotationX = 0;
           drawTimer.Enabled = true;
           //fileSelectBt.BackColor = Color.DeepSkyBlue;
        }
        else
        {
           drawTimer.Enabled = false;
           //fileSelectBt.BackColor = Color.Tomato;

           /* if there is an error, deinitialize the gl monitor to clear the screen */
           glController.glInit(monitor, Batu_GL.Ortho_Mode.CENTER);
           monitor.SwapBuffers();
        }
     }
     else
     {
        // intentionally left blank
     }
  }

  private void drawTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Draw();
  }
```

}
}

Comment: What do mean by *"the size of an object"*? Do you mean the axis aligned bounding box? In view space? In the world? Window coordinates?

Comment: If we figure a box containing the object, I need the width, height and depth of the box

Comment: I see, but do you need the width height and depth in world space or as seen from the camera? Or du you want to know the with and height in window coordinates (pixels)?

Comment: The space it takes in the world space, but may have some use of the window coordinates later too, but mostly in world space

Comment: In this case I don't understand your question. You just have find the minimum and maximum x, y and z coordinate of all the vertices in  `modelVAO.parameterArray`. This can be done in a single loop.

Comment: I will use it to scale the object so no parts will be off the window. will try it once back at home tonight

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        label1.Text = minPos.x + "";
        label2.Text = minPos.y + "";
        label3.Text = minPos.z + "";
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, tnx for contributing. However, please add some explanations. Point out: Why is the given code a solution to the Q. In the best case, a reader very briefly scans the Q, and reads your A, and should be able to understand the whole situation.